# How to enable force feedback in kernel 2.6.34 - 64 bit?

Tags: linux, drivers, usb, kernel-modules

The wheel is `Logitech driving force DFGT`.
The platform:

```
linux-dopx:/home/anisha/ # cat /etc/issue && uname -a 
Welcome to openSUSE 11.3 "Teal" - Kernel \r (\l).
Linux linux-dopx 2.6.34-12-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT 2010-06-29 02:39:08 +0200 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

To check the force feedback I did:

```
linux-dopx:/home/anisha/ # fftest /dev/input/event4
Force feedback test program.
HOLD FIRMLY YOUR WHEEL OR JOYSTICK TO PREVENT DAMAGES

Device /dev/input/event4 opened
Axes query:
Effects:
Number of simultaneous effects: 0
Upload effects[0]: Function not implemented
Upload effects[1]: Function not implemented
Upload effects[2]: Function not implemented
Upload effects[3]: Function not implemented
Upload effects[4]: Function not implemented
Upload effects[5]: Function not implemented
Enter effect number, -1 to exit
```

fftest failed with `Function not implemented` message.
The wheel is being detected through event4 and js0 files in /dev/input/

```
# cat /proc/bus/input/devices
shows:
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046d Product=c29a Version=0111
N: Name="Driving Force GT"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:1d.3-1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event4 js0
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=1f0000 0 0 0 0 0 0 ffff00000000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=30007
B: MSC=10
```

How to counter this? No, I am not running any game. I just wanted to
apply these effects to my wheel.

I even tried `modprobe hid-logitech` and `modprobe hid`, they didn't help.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I replaced the label `LOGITECH_FF` with `LOGIWHEELS_FF` in the file 
  `/usr/src/linux-2.6.34-12/drivers/hid/Kconfig`.
- Set `default y` as shown below:

> ```
> config LOGIWHEELS_FF  
>     bool "Logitech force feedback support"  
>     depends on HID_LOGITECH  
>     default y  
>     select INPUT_FF_MEMLESS  
>     help  
>       Say Y here if you have one of these devices:  
>       -Logitech WingMan Cordless RumblePad  
>       -Logitech WingMan Cordless RumblePad 2  
>       -Logitech WingMan Force 3D  
>       -Logitech Formula Force EX  
>       -Logitech WingMan Formula Force GP  
>       -Logitech MOMO Force wheel  
>
>       and if you want to enable force feedback for them.
>       Note: if you say N here, this device will still be supported, but without
>         force feedback
> ```

The `fftest` worked with constant force as shown below.

```
linux-dopx:/home/anisha/ # fftest /dev/input/event4
Force feedback test program.
HOLD FIRMLY YOUR WHEEL OR JOYSTICK TO PREVENT DAMAGES

Device /dev/input/event4 opened
Axes query: 
Effects: Constant 
Number of simultaneous effects: 16
Upload effects[0]: Invalid argument
Upload effects[2]: Invalid argument
Upload effects[3]: Invalid argument
Upload effects[4]: Invalid argument
Upload effects[5]: Invalid argument
Enter effect number, -1 to exit
1
Now Playing: Constant Force
Enter effect number, -1 to exit
```

Thanks to: *Simon* from *linux-input* mailing list.
http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-input/msg19084.html

Comment: Brainy.. +1 :-)

Comment: I was referring to you, brainy :-)

Answer (score 2):

Some users have [reported](http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3113066.msg237221#msg237221) that testing /dev/input/eventX, and after /dev/input/js0 was the key for them.

An [other](http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3113066.msg237221#msg237221) has tried every possible /dev/input/eventX and finally found a working one.

But it's quite possible that this joystick is not well supported by Linux. On [vdrift wiki](http://wiki.vdrift.net/Enabling_force_feedback_in_kernel), they show how to make a quick patch in order to get a G25 works. Since your Suse Kernel has recognized its name, you should not need to do that. You can also take a look at your dmesg and see if Force Feedback is activated in Suse Kernel, like it's [now the case](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/246952) in Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I managed to solve this.

Comment: This worked in Ubuntu 14.04 when using fftest from the repos (easier than building from source) with XBox 360 Wired Controller. Ended up being event15.